# Extending <Table /> UI with additional button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I would like to add some new functionality to the `<Table />` component pagination. I need something like a button "SHOW ALL" that will cancel any pagination in component and will show all of the table content on **one single** page...

---

So I have to implement two things:
1. Adding new Button SHOW ALL to existing `<Table />` component in exact place (**screen attached**)
[image: SHOW ALL button visual]

2. Find a way to show all of the data on the single page inside `<Table />`

   Is there any workaround or recommended patterns/approach? Maybe some ready-to-use samples?

Answer (score 0):

If you want put that "SHOW ALL" button next to the pagination, you'd have to write `<Table pagination={false} />`, then add your own Pagination component under table then paginate data by yourself.